# Using dict as switch statement in python

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a dictionary as a switch statement to call various methods from user input. What seems to be happening however is that whatever method user selects it then cycles through all of the methods in order of how they are listed in my dictionary rather than exiting after the specific method call.

I am new to Python, having used JAVA which has an switch statement and the ability to use the break keyword inside of the switch which python does not.

I've been digging around on stackoverflow and google without any luck on my particular problem so any help would be appreciated.

Full code is as follows:

```
import pymysql

# Open DB
db = pymysql.connect()

# Prepare a cursor object using  cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create a Student Table
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Student")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Student(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(25))")

# Method for inserting new student mySQL
def insert() :
    name = input('Enter the Students name: ')
    instatmt = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES(NULL, '%s')" % (name)
    cursor.execute(instatmt)
    db.commit()

    return(print("Successfully inserted student"))

# Method for updating a student record mySQL
def update() :
    name = input('Enter the Students name: ')
    update = input('Enter the Updated name: ')

    upstatmt = "UPDATE Student SET Name='%s' WHERE Name='%s'" % (update, name)
    cursor.execute(upstatmt)
    db.commit()

    return(print("Successfully updated object"))

# Method for deleting a student record mySQL
def delete() :
    name = input('Enter the Students name: ')

    delstatmt = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE Name ='%s'" % (name)
    cursor.execute(delstatmt)
    db.commit()

    return(print("Successfully deleted object"))

# Method for retrieving a student record mySQL
def retrieve() :
    name = input('Enter the Students name: ')

    retstatmt = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Name ='%s'" % (name)
    display = cursor.execute(retstatmt)
    print(display)

    return(print("Object Retrieved..."))

# Call method requested by user    
def performAction(argument):

    switcher = {
        'I': insert(),
        'U': update(),
        'D': delete(),
        'R': retrieve(),
        'E': exit
    }
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "Invalid Entry")
    print (func)

# while True :
action = input('Which Operation would you like to perform ( I : Insert, U : Update, D: Delete, R: Retrieve, E: Exit): ')
performAction(action)

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: You're calling the function, rather than referencing the function. Instead of `insert()`, have `insert` (no parenthesis).

Comment: `'I': insert()` this will return one dict with `dict['I']=the result of insert()`, you need to change to `I:insert` instead, then call like `swicther['I']()`

Answer (score 5):

You are invoking the functions instead of inserting them into your dictionary. Try this:

```
def performAction(argument):
    switcher = {
        'I': insert,
        'U': update,
        'D': delete,
        'R': retrieve,
        'E': exit
    }
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "Invalid Entry")
    result = func()
    print (func, result)
```

Comment: Perhaps `result = func() if func != 'Invalid Entry' else None`

Comment: thank you for the help here, oversight on my part calling the functions!

Comment: @Alexander - Perhaps. But I think having `dict.get()` return a default callable makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling functions in your dictionary, so they're all being executed consecutively then never again.  To solve this, remove the parentheses:

```
def performAction(argument):

    switcher = {
        'I': insert,
        'U': update,
        'D': delete,
        'R': retrieve,
        'E': exit
    }
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: print("Invalid Entry"))
    func()
```

Although feasible, this is a non-conventional way of doing what you're 
trying to do, and can be written in a more readable manner:

```
def performAction(argument):
    if argument == 'I':
        insert()
    elif argument == 'U':
        update()
    elif argument == 'D':
        delete()
    elif argument == 'R':
        retrieve()
    elif argument == 'E':
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
```

Python isn't Java, so there's no need to pretend it is.

Comment: I don't think its unconventional. Its just a time-honored jump table.

Comment: @tdelaney It's a python `dict` being used as a switch statement.  Nothing about this is normal or pythonic.

Comment: Use `elif` since the values are mutually exclusive.

Comment: This is most certainly pythonic. Classes use `__dict__` to look up methods. This is the same thing.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! The JAVA is still ingrained so I'm trying to work through different concepts that are different and expand my understanding of python. Thanks for the help here.

Comment: Your `else:` is only attached to the last `if`, so it will print `Invalid Entry` when the enter one of the first 4 actions.

Comment: @tdelaney Ask any seasoned developer during code review which one they would prefer.  99/100 developers would say to use an `if` statement and not an unconventional dictionary approach.

Comment: No way, I am a very seasoned programmer and have run many reviews. This is how class instances are implemented. Its common for switch statements in java and C++ to use hashes instead of pure if/eif. you are just doing an object lookup and operating on that object. Its normal!

Answer (score 0):

To run program with parameters

`updatedb.py --action insert more`

> action = input('Which Operation would you like to perform ( I : Insert, U : Update, D: Delete, R: Retrieve, E: Exit): ')

to be replaced by

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-action", dest="action", nargs=1, default="exit", choices=['insert', 'exit', 'delete'], type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
>>> args
Namespace(action='insert')
>>> args.action
'insert'
```

> performAction(action)

to be replaced by

You can use `eval()` to call the func

```
result = eval(args.action)
```